# How to keep a session using PHP when client has cookies disabled in browser

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am trying to build a simple login portal that uses php sessions to store a users logged-in status. I want the session data to still be available even when cookies are disabled in the users browser.

I have searched the web to find a way of doing this but haven't found anything that gives a good explanation. I'm pretty new to php but have the basic functionality of the web app working except keeping session data stored without cookies.

It's my understanding that when you start a session using session_start(), this creates a cookie that stores the session id. This id can then be passed around the website using cookie or url propagation. The server I am running the site on doesn't allow url propagation so I must use cookies but I don't get how it works if someone turns off cookies in the browser.

Here'e the header.php that I have included in every page:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
if (isset($_POST["LogoutBtn"])) {
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (ini_get("session.use cookies")) {
        $yesterday = time() - (24 * 60 * 60);
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), "", $yesterday, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
    }
    session_destroy();
}

$dataFiles = array("/amacmi01_p1fma/data/DTresults.php", 
                   "/amacmi01_p1fma/data/P1results.php", 
                   "/amacmi01_p1fma/data/PfPresults.php");
$page = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta author="Andrew Macmillan">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php
        $title = "";
        switch ($page) {
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/index.php":
                $title = "BBK DCS Home Page";
                break;
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/admin-login.php":
                $title = "DCS Admin Login";
                break;
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/staff-login.php":
                $title = "DCS Staff Login";
                break;
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/register-staff.php":
                $title = "Register New Staff";
                break;
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/admin-options.php":
                $title = "Admin Options";
                break;
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/intranet.php":
                $title = "BBK DCS Intranet Page";
                break;
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/error.php":
                $title = "Error Viewing Modules";
                break;
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/logged-out.php":
                $title = "Logging Out";
                break;
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/data/DTresults.php":
                $title = "Introduction to Database Technology - DT Results";
                break;
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/data/P1results.php":
                $title = "Web Programming using PHP - P1 Results";
                break;
            case "/amacmi01_p1fma/data/PfPresults.php":
                $title = "Problem Solving for Programming – PfP Results";
                break;
        }
        echo "<title>$title</title>";

        if (in_array($page, $dataFiles)) {
            echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/style.css"/>';
        } else {
            echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"/>';
        }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <?php
        if ($page !== "/amacmi01_p1fma/index.php" && $page !== "/amacmi01_p1fma/logged-out.php") {
            if (in_array($page, $dataFiles)) {
                echo '<div class="home-link">
                         <a href="../index.php">Return to Home Page</a>
                      </div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="home-link">
                         <a href="index.php">Return to Home Page</a>
                      </div>';                    
            }
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION["LoggedIn"]) && $page !== "/amacmi01_p1fma/logged-out.php") {
            $homeLink = "";
            if (in_array($page, $dataFiles)) {
                $homeLink = "../logged-out.php";
            } else{
                $homeLink = "logged-out.php";
            }
            echo '<div id="logout-form">
                       <form action="'.$homeLink.'" method="post">
                            <label for="logout-btn">You are logged in as '.$_SESSION["UserName"].'</label>
                            <input type="submit" name="LogoutBtn" id="logout-btn" value="Logout"/>
                       </form>
                  </div>';
        }
        ?>
    </header>
```

Comment: It passes the SID in the URL https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Comment: Before you just blindly copy paste code without understanding the issue: If a user disables cookies on their browser, you need an alternative on how PHP will handle the session. I don't see any of that in this code. @AbraCadaver that is a dangerous solution. If one would be to copy that url and share it somewhere... that session is wide open. But I still <3 you for being active and providing a solution regardless. ^.^

Comment: If a user doesn't have cookies enabled and your web server doesn't allows for URL propagation, you're in a bind. In my opinion, requiring the user to turn on cookies to safely be able to log in to a site isn't too much to ask. I mean, the client will need to pass the session id (or some form of token) to the server somehow.

Comment: @Xorifelse I admit that I do not completely understand the subject but am trying to learn the best i can with online resources. What alternatives are there and do you have any suggestions on where i can find information to learn about them? Thanks

Comment: I can only suggest to take a look at this, and provide some sort of "middleware". https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php Mainly because the issue you're having has to do with OCD. I would recommend kicking of the users who don't have them enabled as this is a minority.